# convert a SecureRandom byte to string without coding problem in java

Tags: java

I am using this code snippnet to convert byte to string in Java 8:

```
 SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
 byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
 random.nextBytes(bytes);
 String salt = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

but the output salt is like this:

```
0����8���t��.1�A
```

is it possible to make it as a flat string or pass from url parameter?

Comment: How about encoding it as base 64?

Comment: Or hex? Octal? Decimal?

Comment: follow your tips , I am using base64 now @Sweeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode it to Base 64:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
random.nextBytes(bytes);

byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
System.out.println(new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Output:

```
DBL53Wdublx4iN7gU/+5jNy7mes=
```

Comment: Note there is a 'URL safe' variant of base64 defined in rfc4648, prominently used by JWS/JWE/JWT, and also implemented in `java.util.Base64`, that changes the alphabet to avoid percent-encoding in a URL or x-www-form-urlencoded.